# Text modify, using "content"?

Tags: css

i try to **change the text of button** with **css** but it doesn't work.

I tryed to use **content: "sth"** but it doesn't work.

```css
button.mainMenu {
  content: "-";
}

button.mainMenu:hover {
  content: "X";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button class="mainMenu" type="button">
    </button>
</body>
```

It displays nothing in the box :/

Comment: hover will not work. may be someone can help but content can add like this `button.mainMenu:before {
  display: block;
  content: " - ";
}
button.mainMenu {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    color: red;
}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) only works with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements

```css
button.mainMenu::before {
  content: "-";
}

button.mainMenu:hover::before {
  content: "X";
}
```

```html
<button class="mainMenu" type="button"></button>
```